# Failed to parse SourceMap: al cargar archivo CSS en Chrome

Tags: bootstrap, css3, google-chrome

En la cabecera de mi página tengo enlazados algunos archivos [css](/questions/tagged/css) de los cuales cargan perfectamente sus estilos, pero al abrir la ventana "**Developer Tools**" de Google Chrome me muestra un error en la parte inferior "**Console**":

Failed to parse SourceMap: 
http://milocalhost:puerto/nombreProyecto/folder/recurso.css.map

Teniendo en cuenta que los estilos cargan perfectamente.
¿qué podrá ser?

Answer (score 6):

pude solucionar el inconveniente tan solo eliminando la ultima linea comentada del archivo bootstrap.css:

/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */

guardé nuevamente el archivo CSS y al recargar la página ya no aparecía el mensaje de error en la consola de chrome, para quienes tengan este pequeño inconveniente ya está resuelto, saludos.

Comment: También puedes buscar el fichero `.css.map` y servirlo desde tu servidor. Así cuando tu navegador lo solicite lo encontrará y no te dará error. Los [sourcemaps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) pueden ser un buen aliado del desarrollador y siempre se debe considerar la posibilidad de incluirlos en lugar de excluirlos. Esto por supuesto depende de tus necesidades y ninguna regla te obliga a usarlos.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Opciones de crome]

Basta con que te dirijas a inspeccionar >> settings (f1) >> deshabilites las opciones